# Parsing XML file in C# - how to report errors

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

First I load the file in a structure

```
XElement xTree = XElement.Load(xml_file);
```

Then I create an enumerable collection of the elements.

```
 IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xTree.Elements();
```

And iterate elements

```
foreach (XElement el in elements)
{
}
```

The problem is - when I fail to parse the element (a user made a typo or inserted a wrong value) - how can I report exact line in the file?
Is there any way to tie an element to its corresponding line in the file?

Comment: can you show xml file Attribute?

Comment: every node looks like  
<Test Group="Maintenance Test" SubGroup="USB" Name="Verify Copied Text">
    <ExeName>CopyPasteFile.exe</ExeName>
    <ExeMode>Console</ExeMode>
    <RunMode>Normal</RunMode>
    <TestType>String</TestType>
    <Group>Main</Group>
  </Test>

Comment: If there is an error in parsing the xml then the exception will already provide the line number. Is that what you mean, or are you talking about valid xml, but invalid data according to your business rules?

Comment: The file is perfectly valid in XML format sense. But a user may type  <ExeMode>Bla bla  bla</ExeMode> instead of <ExeMode>Console</ExeMode>. So I want to report - Bla bla  bla is an invalid value at line number #???. The file has 4000 nodes so to go through all nodes looking for the  mistake is some pain.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it. Since xml is not guaranteed to be more than one line I assume its tricky. Maybe look at the source code for XmlReader to see how it is handled there.

Comment: if XmlReader reads form the file directly it may be solution. In this case I have to rewrite the whole parsing method which quite huge.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it (although not a proper one) –

When you find a wrong value, add an invalid char (e.g. ‘<’) to it.

So instead of: `<ExeMode>Bla bla bla</ExeMode>`
You’ll have: `<ExeMode><Bla bla bla</ExeMode>`

Then load the XML again with try / catch (System.Xml.XmlException ex).

This XmlException has LineNumber and LinePosition.

Comment: well...it's definitely creative one. :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limited set of acceptable values, I believe XML Schemas have the concept of an enumerated type -- so write a schema for the file and have the parser validate against that. Assuming the parser you're using supports Schemas, which most should by now.

I haven't looked at DTDs in decades, but they may have the same kind of capability.

Otherwise, you would have to consider this semantic checking rather than syntactic checking, and that makes it your application's responsibility. If you are using a SAX parser and interpreting the data as you go, you *may* be able to get the line number; check your parser's features.

Otherwise the best answer I've found is to report the problem using an xpath to the affected node/token rather than a line number. You may be able to find a canned solution for that, either as a routine to run against a DOM tree or as a state machine you can run alongside your SAX code to track the path as you go.

(All the "maybe"s are because I haven't looked at what's currently available in a very long time, and because I'm trying to give an answer that is valid for all languages and parser implementations. This should still get you pointed in some useful directions.)